# jquery which run inside infinite loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have one j query script which run infinitely to check whether audio play or not. If audio play then it send how much portion of audio have played by user? I just want to know, will browser hang after some time due to continuous script running? if yes then what will be the best solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the [javascript setTimeout](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp) function to check every second or so otherwise you will surely cause a very slow or hanging response for the end user